How/where to attach bird deterrent on outside corner of overhanging eave
This woodpecker is pecking on the gutter every morning at 4:30.  Always at the extreme outside corner, as shown.
I want to try attaching a plastic decoy woodpecker at that corner.  Not sure of the best approach, as none of them are great.

drill a small hole in the upper outside edge of the gutter and attach it with a nut and bolt.  I don't know what negative consequences that will have on the gutter.
use an J-shaped metal arm screwed to the wood underside of the eave and reaching out and up.  Ugly. Seems complicated.  The arm will need to be pretty heavy to be strong enough.
The roof?   Seems like the worst idea but just for completeness ... glue to the shingles?  Nail an arm underneath the shingles?

The dormer you see behind the corner is several feet away, too far to be useful.


Not sure if fake woodpecker (competition!) would be any more effective than a fake owl, (threat!) though often birds are smart enough to figure out the fakes after a few days so neither works. If a fake owl works it might be able to be "effective" without being on the exact point the woodpecker likes to bang, just in clear view of it.

That's just what woodpeckers are known to do:  https://www.fws.gov/story/woodpeckers-and-your-home#:~:text=Sometimes%20woodpeckers%20are%20only%20looking,start%20of%20the%20breeding%20season.

Get a small spring clamp, attach the decoy to the clamp by whatever method is easiest, clamp the decoy to the edge of the gutter, where Woody is perched in your photo?

@Huesmann I love it.  Except, it's about 30 feet up, above the driveway and side door.  I don't want it falling on someone.  I have to think about this and practice on a lower part of the roof.  If I can make it reliable, and maybe even rig up a way to install it using a pole and no ladder, that would be brilliant.

@jay613 tether it to the drain pipe with a piece of fishing line?

Screw a block of wood to the decoy and just stand it in the gutter. No need to get all complicated or permanent. The right size block will rest snugly in the upper part of the gutter so water can still flow under, and it will be long enough to be stable. Use some wood or rubber standoffs if it doesn't stay off the gutter floor enough.
Note that the 'pecker is drumming as a mating attractant. The period of time that it'll do this is fairly short. It's probably about done already. Looks like a Hairy, based on location, size and plumage. It could also be a Sapsucker, which I've witnessed drumming on steel power pole cable sheaths. ("The acoustics in here are amazing!")

Damn good ID'ing for such a poor photo!  I've seen both of those on the feeder.

Wonderful solution.  I was planning on hiring someone to install this on my high gutter but this way I could do it myself from the ground and easily move it.  So far, effective over three days but as you point out that's no proof.   +1000 if I could for a ladder-free solution.

See my pics in new answer.

You could get a metal disc, like a big washer, and wrap it in plastic (to prevent rust), and use some poly sealant to glue it to the edge of the gutter. Glue a magnet to your decoy.
Depending on your gutter's mounting system, you could attach metal discs to several of the gutter mounts and have more than one decoy or decoy position.

Implementation photos for @isherwood solution.
First pic, templated and tuned the mount on a gutter I could reach with a 6 foot stepladder.  Second one, I tried to build an adapter for my 16 foot pole.  You can buy male broomstick adapters easily, but not female ones. I thought it would be cool to tap the broomstick thread into the block of wood but I guess I'll save that for a very rainy day. It turned out the pole end fit perfectly between Woody's legs.  Snug enough for installing and easy to wiggle or rotate out.


Chunk of 2x4 inside the gutter heavy enough to keep it there and a couple of leftover hardwood strips for the mount.    If this is effective I'll replace those with something lower profile.
